# How to import scss-file in scss-file?

Tags: angular, sass

I use a lot variables in scss. so i create file which contain all scss-variables. Now i need import this file to another scss-files.

My try:

1. create file scss-vars.scss in root catalog
2. write in tsconfig.json:

```
"@bla/blaa/a/scss-vars":["libs/ui/scss-vars.scss"],
```

3. in all scss-files use follow import:

```
@import "@bla/blaa/a/scss-vars.scss";
```

But in result i get follow error message in console:

> Can't find stylesheet to import.

I need import scss file without absolute path use.

Comment: Generally doing it [this way](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-shortcut-to-importing-styles-files-in-components#toc-shortcut-with-angular-cli-configuration) makes life much easier.

Comment: @Patrik Alexits but it approachs are not work for scss. They are work only for sass

Answer (score 1):

You can create an alias for your folders in the angular.json file.

Just search for 'styles.scss' and you will find where to add any other path you'd like.

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "src/my-folder/some-styles.scss", // now you can import some-styles globally
        ],
```

in some random-file.scss

`@import 'some-styles';`

Answer (score 0):

CSS preprocessors do not look at `tsconfig.json` paths. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9018) on the Angular CLI repo regarding this topic.